# RSPEC validate failed : Document_type is not included in the list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I added a validate for my order model:

```
validates :document_type, inclusion: { in: %w(boleta factura) },
  allow_nil: true
```

My spec/fatories/orders.rb:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
 factory :order do
  status 'MyString'
  order_date '2016-02-16 13:44:01'
  delivery_date '2016-02-16 13:44:01'
  subtotal '9.99'
  igv '9.99'
  total '9.99'
  document_type 'MyString'
  store { FactoryGirl.build(:store) }
  order_items { [FactoryGirl.build(:order_item)] }
  user { FactoryGirl.build(:user) }
end
end
```

But when I run "rspec" this failed and showed me this:

```
1) OrderItemsController POST create redirects
 Failure/Error: @order = FactoryGirl.create(:order)

 ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
   Validate failed : Document type is not included in the list
 # ./spec/controllers/order_items_controller_spec.rb:4:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
  2) OrderItemsController DELETE destroy redirects
 Failure/Error: @order = FactoryGirl.create(:order)

 ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
   Validate failed : Document type is not included in the list
 # ./spec/controllers/order_items_controller_spec.rb:37:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
 3) OrderItemsController PUT update redirects
 Failure/Error: @order = FactoryGirl.create(:order)

 ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
   Validate failed : Document type is not included in the list
 # ./spec/controllers/order_items_controller_spec.rb:26:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
  4) OrderItemsController PATCH update redirects
 Failure/Error: @order = FactoryGirl.create(:order)

 ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
   Validate failed : Document type is not included in the list
 # ./spec/controllers/order_items_controller_spec.rb:15:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

How can I add `document_type` to the list?

Comment: Update the question with `spec/factories/order.rb` content.

Comment: Try  `document_type ["boleta", "factura"].sample` instead of `document_type 'MyString'`

Comment: @Pavan its not work :( , it show me the  same failed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with the following:

```
validates :document_type, inclusion: { in: %w(boleta factura) },
  allow_nil: true
```

you are specifying that `document_type` must be `boleta` or `factura`.

However your Factory is setting `document_type` to `MyString`, so for that reason you are getting the validation error.

To solve your problem change your factory to set `document_type` as `boleta` or `factura` OR just remove that field, since you are allowing nil (`allow_nil`).

```
FactoryGirl.define do
 factory :order do
  status 'MyString'
  order_date '2016-02-16 13:44:01'
  delivery_date '2016-02-16 13:44:01'
  subtotal '9.99'
  igv '9.99'
  total '9.99'
  document_type 'boleta' # or factura or remove this line
  store { FactoryGirl.build(:store) }
  order_items { [FactoryGirl.build(:order_item)] }
  user { FactoryGirl.build(:user) }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap an array sample in a block.

```
document_type { ["boleta", "factura"].sample }
```